# Highcharts not plotting textbox values

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to add points to already plotted series as under

```
chart.AddJavascripFunction("ChartClickEvent", @"var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                series = this.series[0];
                series.addPoint([x,y]);","e");
```

it works fine, but when i try to get values of x and y from textboxes it does'nt work.

```
chart.AddJavascripFunction("ChartClickEvent", @"
                series = this.series[0];
                series.addPoint([textbox1.Text,textbox2.Text]);","e");
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please be more specific, add more sample code and correct your tags (as this has nothing to do with c#)

Comment: i have edited it, because i am new here,will not be able to write down perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your values are not number, but strings only. Try to replace this line:

```
series.addPoint([textbox1.Text,textbox2.Text]);","e");
```

with

```
series.addPoint([parseFloat(textbox1.Text),parseFloat(textbox2.Text)]);","e");
```